# Warning: This application's locale, tr, is not supported by all of its localization delegates. Error

Tags: flutter

[Warning: This application's locale, tr, is not supported by all of its localization delegates. Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsRIa.png)

Comment: Please add your `MaterialApp` and any other localization configuration that you may have added for better understanding.